# Why can't I return an index of an array as int in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, int, return

Apparently Eclipse keeps giving me an error asking me to return an int. Is `array[i]` not considered an `int` or we cant return an index of a array in java like this? Anyone out there that can help me?

```
public static void main(String[] args){     
    int[] array = {10,6,4,3,12,19,18};
    int z = quick_find_1d_peak1(array);
    System.out.println(z);
}

public static int quick_find_1d_peak1(int[] inputArray){
    for (int i=0 ; i<inputArray.length ; ){
        if (i==0 && inputArray[i] >= inputArray[i+1]){
            return inputArray[i];
        } else if (i==inputArray.length && inputArray[i] >= inputArray[i-1]){
            return inputArray[i];
        } else if (inputArray[i] >= inputArray[i-1] && inputArray[i] >= inputArray[i+1]){
            return inputArray[i];
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not directly related to you question, but the condition in the first `else` clause will never be true, so the code there will never be executed. (Should it read `i==inputArray.length-1 && ...` instead?)

Answer (score 2):

In `quick_find_1d_peak1`, your last conditional (the `else`) doesn't return anything. This means it is possible nothing gets returned ever. To fix this, either return something in the `else` (which is probably not what you want to do because you're incrementing `i` to go to the next one), or return something after the for loop so something will get returned no matter what.

Answer (score 2):

You're not guaranteed to return a result. For example, suppose inputArray is empty, then the for loop never gets entered, and nothing is returned. Or if none of the conditions inside the loop ever fire, then your `else` doesn't return anything.

You have to guarantee that you return something in a method (or throw an exception).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a try-catch block or return something if none of your conditions are fullfiled(like default in a switch perhaps).

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/22661-exception-basics-try-catch-finally/

Hope this helps.

Cheers!